# GnuPG homedir read/write permission

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt a tar file with GnuPG through a Python script on Win7.

```
filename_e_archive = askopenfilename()
current_directory = os.path.abspath('.')
folder_d_archive = filename_e_archive.split('.elog')[0]
filename_d_archive = folder_d_archive + ".tar.gz"
path_to_e_archive = os.path.dirname(filename_e_archive)
path_to_d_archive = os.path.join(path_to_e_archive,'/',folder_d_archive)
os.makedirs(path_to_d_archive)
os.chdir(path_to_d_archive)

gpg = gnupg.GPG()

with open(filename_e_archive, 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase='mypassword',output=filename_d_archive)
```

When run I got the following error:

> C:\LA>python test.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "test.py", line 30, in 
>       gpg = gnupg.GPG()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg\gnupg.py", line 125, in **init**
>       ignore_homedir_permissions=ignore_homedir_permissions,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg_meta.py", line 183, in **init**
>       self.homedir = os.path.expanduser(home) if home else _util._conf   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg_util.py", line 765, in
>   **set**
>       getattr(obj, self.fset.**name**)(value)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg_meta.py", line 440, in
>   _homedir_set ter
>       raise RuntimeError(str(ae)) RuntimeError: Homedir ''C:\LA\gnupghome.config\python-gnupg'' needs read/write permissions
>
> C:\LA>

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issue by removing the gnupg library:

> pip uninstall gnupg

and installing the phyton-gnupg one

> pip install python-gnupg

Docs: [python-gnupg - A Python wrapper for GnuPG](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was also present with the latest version. Removing the gnupg and installing the python-gnupg solved the matter on win11/pycharm 2022.3